# Is $ \ \mathcal{P}(A\cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B)$ True?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a feeling it is true, but cannot find a way to prove it.

Help is welcome =)

Comment: What does $\mathcal{P}(A)$ mean here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this statement is true.  Let $x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$.  Then, by the definition of the power set, $x \subseteq A \cap B$, which by definition of intersection implies that $x \subseteq A$ and $x \subseteq B$.  So by definition of power set, $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$.  Hence, $x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$.  We have shown that $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$.  It's true that $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$ by "reversing" the proof of $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$.  Rewrite that to obtain the equivalence of both sets.

Comment: You should reason by equivalence.

Comment: Yes, I added more to my answer already

Comment: So you deserve +1

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple equivalency proof :

$ E \in \mathcal P (A\cap B)  \Leftrightarrow E\subset A\cap B
\Leftrightarrow \left[E\subset A \textrm{ and  } E\subset B\right] \Leftrightarrow \left[E\in\mathcal P (A) \textrm{ and } E\in \mathcal P(B) \right]\Leftrightarrow E\in\mathcal P (A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$

You should maybe show carefully this equivalence :
$$E\subset A\cap B
\Leftrightarrow \left[E\subset A \textrm{ and  } E\subset B\right]$$
going back to the definition : $E\subset F \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in E, x\in F$.