# Prove Properties of Sets and Powersets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

a) $\wp(A \cap B)=\wp(A) \cap \wp(B)$.
b) $\wp(A) \cup \wp(B) \subset \wp(A \cup B)$.
c) IF $A \subset B,$ Then $\wp(A) \subset \wp(B)$.
d) $A \subset B \quad$ IF $\quad A \cap C B=\varnothing$.
e) $(A-B) \cup(B-A)=(A \cup B)-(A \cap B)$

I studied the essential part of sets but I have no idea of how to solve these.
But even so I tried to come to some conclusions about some items so you can help me more easily.

**Solve only the ones I commented.**

a) The power set of $A ∩ B$ will have the possible subsets containing the commom elements between them. its cardinality will be $2^z$ assuming that $z$ contains the number of elements of $A∩B$. The right hand side I'm gonna take the powerset of $A$ and $B$ separately and then make the interception, There will be common subsets only with the elements that are both in $A$ and in $B$.

c) It says that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, so $A$ has less elements than $B$. as $A$ has less elements than $B$, the powerset of $A$ will be 2 to the $|A|$, as $|A| < |B|$, the power set of $B$ will have more subsets.

e)$(A - B)$ means We will get only the elements that are only in the set $A$, and $(B - A)$ means We will get only the elements that are only in the set $B$, putting it all together We will have a set with only the exclusive elements of the 2 sets.

The right hand side, $(A ∪ B)$ means We will put all the elements together. $(A ∩ B)$ means We will have only the commom elements between set $A$ and $B$, because of the subtraction We will remove the elements that are in both sets at the same time. The conclusion is that left hand side = right hand side.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Too many questions. One at a time?

Comment: @Jack You don't need to do all.

Comment: Usually a set "equality" ($A=B$) will be proved in two steps: 1) $A \subseteq B$ and 2) $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: Thus, for a) try with a1) $\mathcal P (A \cap B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B)$ and a2) $\mathcal P(A) \cap \mathcal P(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A \cap B)$

Comment: How to do them ? for a1) consider a set $x \in \mathcal P(A \cap B)$: this means that $x$ is a *subset* of the *intersection* of $A$ **and** $B$, i.e. is a subset of **both** $A$ and $B$. And so on...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What is the name of these properties You used ? I'll study them in detail, thanks.

Comment: "I studied the essential part of sets ..." Where ? Textbook, lectures, Wiki ? You will find them in any "resource" dealing with elementary set theory.

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Sure, thanks.

Comment: BTW you can probably find posts about at least some of these here on the site. [By this search in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24P(A%5Ccap%20B)%3DP(A)%5Ccap%20P(B)%24&p=1), I get:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499746/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706649/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987989/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713312/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268091/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551681/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168852/
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110845/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to prove that the cardinalities are the same, not that the sets are the same.

(a)$X\in\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ iff

$X\subset A\cap B$ iff

$X\subset A$ and $X\subset B$ iff

$X\in\mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B)$

(b)$X\in\mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ iff

$X\subset A$ or $X\subset B$ then

$X\subset A\cup B$ iff

$X\in\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$

(c) $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ iff

$X\subset A \subset B$ then

$X\subset B$ which is equivalent to

$X\in\mathcal{P}(B)$

(d) $A\subset B$ iff for any $x\in A$ then $x\in B$,
Take $x\in A\cap B^c$, then $x \in A$ and $x\notin B$, but this clearly contradicts our assumption "if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$", so $A\cap B^c=\emptyset$. Conversely $A\cap B^c=\emptyset$, then if $x\notin B$ we can say $x\notin A$, but this is equivalent to $x\in A$ then $x\in B$.

(e) $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ iff

$x\in (A\setminus B)$ or $x\in(B\setminus A)$ iff

$(x\in A$ and $x\notin B)$ or $(x\in B$ and $x\notin A)$ iff

$(x\in A$ or $x\in B)$ and $(x\notin A$ or $x\notin B)$ iff

$x\in (A\cup B)$ and $x\notin (A\cap B)$ iff

$x\in (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$.

One uses basic logic properties such as commutativity for conjunctions, th use of negations, the contraposition of formulas and subsets properties like if $X\subset A$ or $X\subset B$ then $X\subset A\cup B$ (which you can reduce to a formula). And one uses the definition of equality of sets: two sets are the same if the have the same elements i.e. $A=B$ when and only when, $x\in A$ is equivalent to $x\in B$. (iff abreviates if and only if)

Comment: Hello Edgard, Is there any book you recommend to learn sets ?

Comment: To learn elementary set theory: functions, power set and such i'd recommend chapter 1 of Topology by James Munkres. To learn  intermediate-advanced stuff maybe the Set Theory by Jech. I learned by transalting a german book: http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/mildenberger/veranstaltungen/ws15/ax_2016_02_07.pdf But it is intermediate stuff

Comment: @hjx Check again the last answer. It was wrong. I've just corrected

Comment: @edgard I was reading the book 'topology' that You recommended, and I'm a bit confused about your answer for the e), according to the book We treat the 'or' to be either one or the other or both. in this part $ x\in(A\setminus B)$ or $x\in(B\setminus A)$ x can't be an exclusive element  of A and exclusive of B at the same time.

Comment: @hjx or is always inclusive in common math, i.e. it includes the possibility of the two events to happen at the same time. Xor is the exclusive disjunction, it excludes that possibility. In this case we are looking at an xor proposition: it cannot be an element of bothe sets at the same time, but it can be an element of either one. In set theoretic notation this "xor" is translated to an operator called simmetric difference, which is defined exactly as in exercise (e) $A\bigtriangleup B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$

Comment: Got it, Clear up another thing, I din't understand this, $x\in (A\cup B)$ and $x\notin (A\cup B)$, How can x be in a set and not to be in it at the same time. I think it should be  $x\in (A\cup B)$ and $x\notin (A ∩ B)$

Comment: @hjx yes you're right, it should be $x\notin (A\cap B)$, i'll correct it

Comment: @Edgard I thought your answer for the d) very confused, could you explain it again ?, As it is a double implication You must proof both the going and the return. and I get mixed up about the contradictions you mentioned.

Comment: $x\in A\to x\in B$ is one of the hypotheses. And if $A\cap B^c\neq\emptyset$ then there is $x\in A\wedge x\notin B$ which is equivalent to $\neg(x\in A\to x\in B)$. So one gets, from assuming $A\cap B^c\neq\emptyset$, a contradiction. And for the second hypothesis, $A\cap B^c=\emptyset$, is to say for all $x$, $x\notin A\cap B^c$, this last is equivalent to $x\notin A \vee x\in B$, and this is equivalent to $x\in A \to x\in B.$