# Proving that if A ⊆ B, then A ⊆ B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In an attempt to prove that if $A ⊆ B$, then $A ⊆ B$; I have conjured the following proof:

We must show that whenever $X ∈ A$, then $X ∈ B$; From $X ∈ A$ it follows that $X ⊆ A$. If we denote $z$ to be any element in $X$, then from $X ⊆ A$ it follows that $z ∈ A$; And from $A ⊆ B$ that $z ∈ B$. We have shown that any element of $X$ must be an element of $B$, hence we say that $X 
⊆ B$. And from this it follows that $X ∈ B$. Therefore we have shown that any element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

The question of interest: is this proof valid? I ask because I am relatively new to forming set-theoretic proofs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your proof is valid but you might simply use, without (re)proving it, that $\subseteq$ is transitive, like in [Prove Properties of Sets and Powersets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2366063/prove-properties-of-sets-and-powersets).

Comment: The proof you have written is correct

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: It's valid.  I empathize with new students that it hard to know exactly what the rituals of formal proofs are.  But in the end we *aren't* priests putting on robes chanting archaic tongues (even though it sometimes look like it). It's okay to talk plain...  In this statement $A\subset B$ means all elements of $A$ are elements of $A$. So any set constructed solely of elements of  $A$ is constructed solely of elements of $B$ as all elements of $A$ are elements of $B$. So every subset of A is a subset of B. So the set of subsets of A is a subset of the set of subsets of B. .. You can be casual.

Comment: Still, it's very elegant proof and shows good grasps of the concepts.  (Grasp on the concepts is really the only important aspect of a proof of statements like these).  Good job.

Comment: @fleablood thank you much for the wonderful comment! While I do admire the goegeous structure of how set-theory has been organized, it does prove quite the challenging when you perform it in practice. I've currently started off with Halmos' book on Naive Set Theory, but it would be of big help to hear some recommendations from the more profesional. I'm trying to read as much as I can before I become an undergrad. Much thanks again for your affirmation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is valid. We can perhaps take it back to show OP how to do it (I'm not a specialist but I can try.)
Suppose $A\subset B$.
Then $(\forall X)(X\subset A )\implies (X\subset A \text{ and }  A\subset B )\implies (X \subset B)$,
otherwise written $(\forall X)X\in A \implies X \in B$, that's to say $A \subset B$. Q.E.D.

Comment: I've only ever seen Q.E.D. used in geometrical proofs. Would it's reference here be appropriate?

Comment: Of course, this simply means "what needed to be demonstrated"(quod erat demonstrandum). In French we write "C.Q.F.D."(Ce qu'il Fallait Démontrer)